# Delete statement takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-execution-plan

I have a `ProfileAvatars` table with 1000 rows that is the parent table for `UserProfile` table with 16,557,010 rows.

When I add a new picture (without any child record in `UserProfile`) and I want to delete it, the `Delete` statement takes 5-12 seconds to complete the delete query.

This is my query:

```sql
DELETE FROM ProfileAvatars
WHERE ProfileAvatarId = 10
```

Here is the execution plan:

[image]

Why is my `delete` statement taking so long? How can I reduce time needed to delete a single row?

---

Tables definition

`ProfileAvatars`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [gnr].[ProfileAvatars](
    [ProfileAvatarId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [AvatarPictuerPath] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CreateBy] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateUTC] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProfileAvatars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProfileAvatarId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`UserProfile`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [sqr].[UserProfile](
    [ProfileId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ProfileCaption] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ProfileAvatarId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MediaAgeRangeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsKid] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDefault] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateBy] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [DeletedDateUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [UserTasteInsertionDateUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserTasteStatus] [int] NULL,
    [UserTasteSkipDateUTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [PinCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [IsLock] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserProfile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProfileId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [sqr].[UserProfile] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UserProfile_IsDeleted]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDeleted]
GO
ALTER TABLE [sqr].[UserProfile] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UserProfile_IsLock]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsLock]
GO
ALTER TABLE [sqr].[UserProfile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfile_MediaAgeRange] FOREIGN KEY([MediaAgeRangeId])
REFERENCES [gnr].[MediaAgeRange] ([MediaAgeRangeId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [sqr].[UserProfile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfile_MediaAgeRange]
GO
ALTER TABLE [sqr].[UserProfile]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfile_ProfileAvatars] FOREIGN KEY([ProfileAvatarId])
REFERENCES [gnr].[ProfileAvatars] ([ProfileAvatarId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [sqr].[UserProfile] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_UserProfile_ProfileAvatars]
GO
```

Comment: Questtions about performance require the table and index definitions and please add the actual execution plan [paste-the-plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Also which version `select @@version` of SQL Server

Comment: Please show both table definitions, and any indexes you have on them.

Comment: Is this the full query that you are sharing with us, we will also need the table definitions?
Based on the execution plan I can see that you are performing a scan on the UserProfile table which would be impacting your performance due to it having to search through all of the records in a non-efficient/non-indexed way.

Comment: It needs to do a scan of the 16 million row table to validate the delete wont leave foreign key orphans you should add an index on that column

Comment: What Martin said

Comment: @MartinSmith I should add `NONCLUSTERED` or `CLUSTERED` index ?

Comment: You already have a clustered index on the table, you can't create a second on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a non-clustered index on your UserProfile table
`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_UserProfile_ProfileAvatarId ON sqr.UserProfile (ProfileAvatarId);`

This will change the scan (that is currently in the plan for foreign key validation) into a seek. A scan is more costly due to the query running through the whole table to find what it needs. By adding the index it gives the query an idea of where to look and turns the scan into a seek.

[image]